# Track down the slope of the phone left and right

Tags: java, android

Good day, i make an application, and when tilting the phone right in my phone card should turn right and turn left when you lean to the left. How can i using a gyroscope to track these movements? Searching the internet and have not found anything like it. Maybe you have similar examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your android-sdk folder for the samples, should find something like `samples/android-XX/AccelerometerPlay` that shows how to use accelerometer.